# What is the difference between the structure "should do" and "should be doing"?

Tags: modal-verbs

What is the difference between the following sentences.

> No one **should live** in this house, as it is decrepit.
>
> No one **should be living** in this house, as it is decrepit.
>
> You **should help** your mom. She can't do all the work.
>
> You **should be helping** your mom. She can't do all the work.

Does the use "should do" feel more urgent?

Comment: I should answer your question. I should be answering your question (or doing my work instead). Now, please, can you tell me the difference? It's it about urgency?

Comment: Now I realize that yes. It is about urgency. "You should be answering your questions" means you it is imperetive that you answer it at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **should** in as sentence is suggestive as to an action.

> You should help your mom. She can't do all the work.

This is fairly generic. It can be used to suggest a present action (something you currently may need to be doing), or be suggestive of a future potential action.

For example, the mother may be picking up the kids clothes off the floor and the father is informing to the kid, that he thinks the kid should be assisting his / her mother. He is not directing or telling the the kid to go assist his / her mother right now (or even in the future), it's only a suggestion as to an action the kid can take.

> You should be helping your mom. She can't do all the work.

This is little less generic as this applies to something happening currently (present).

For example, here the father's suggestion is a little more specific as the father is suggesting the kid go help his / her mother now, instead of whatever the kid is currently doing.

... so yes, "should **be**" adds a small amount of urgency.

Answer (score 0):

"No one should be living ..." implies someone is living in the house, and they shouldn't be.  "No one should live ..." makes more sense if there is no one living in the house now.

"You should help ..." is a more gentle suggestion than "You should be helping..."  "You should be helping ..." implies that you should already be helping your mom, without being asked to do so.